# Prove there is no neighborhood of $0$ on which $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Tags: real-analysis

I have $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
x-x^2 & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb Q \\
x+x^2 & \text{ if } x\notin \mathbb Q.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
What I've done so far is: say $I$ is a neighborhood of $0$, so $\exists \varepsilon>0: (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\subseteq I.$ The density of the irrationals implies $\exists \alpha\in (0,\varepsilon)$ with $\alpha$ irrational. Now I'm trying to prove that there exists some rational number $\beta\in (\alpha,\varepsilon)$ where $f(\beta)<f(\alpha).$ Any tips on pinning $\beta$ down (without getting too messy)?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: $x - x^2 > 0$ for $0 < x < 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just solved it actually. Consider the function $g(x) = \alpha + \alpha^2 - (x-x^2).$ Then $g(\alpha) = 2\alpha^2>0,$ and since $g$ is continuous, $\exists \delta > 0: \forall x\in B_\delta(\alpha),$ $g(x)\in B_{2\alpha^2} g(\alpha),$ that is, $g(x)>0.$ Let $m=\min(\alpha+\delta,\varepsilon).$ By the density of the rationals there exists a rational $\beta\in (\alpha,m).$ Then $\alpha,\beta\in I$ and $\alpha < \beta$ but $f(\alpha)>f(\beta).$

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion** Draw the graphs of both parabolas to see the configuration around $0$.

It should be clear that the graph of $x+x^2$ lies above that of $x-x^2$ on $(0, \epsilon)$ for a small $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that there is a neighborhood $(a,b)$ such that $0 \in (a,b)$. Then there must exist $\delta > 0$ such that $(-\delta, \delta \subset(a,b)$ and $0 \in (-\delta, \delta)$. Choose an irrational $s \in (0, \delta)$, then a rational $r \in (s, \min\{s+s^2, \delta)$. We may find $r$ since $s < s + s^2$. Then

$$
f(r) = r - r^2 < r < s + s^2 = f(s) \;,
$$
giving a contradiction.